# Use router to display component in the root component

Tags: angular

I want to integrate angular 2 application into an existing application which is using freemarker.

I want to use the router to display the correct component by giving the name of the component to the root component.

```
<my-app displayComponent="myComponent">Loading...</my-app>
```

I can retrieve the componentToDisplay property in the root component, but then it does not work when I try to navigate to the component myComponent.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    displayComponent: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, private elm: ElementRef) {
      this.displayComponent = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('displayComponent');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.navigate([this.displayComponent]);
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the route logic to your `Routes`?

```
{
   path: 'component/path',
   component: ComponentName
}
```

Comment: Yes, just in case I tried to call the navigate function with the same component under a child component, and it works. So the problem is that navigate function does not work in the root component.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for now :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate([this.displayComponent]));
}
```